# making proxy authentication server in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, http-proxy

I want to make a proxy server in python django (3.0) like the one at the following link:

https://blogs.oracle.com/wssfc/handling-proxy-server-authentication-requests-in-java

Comment: "I want to make a proxy server...." And the problem/issue is?

Comment: The problem is how to make this proxy authentication server